# For a longitudinal observational study, what is the best method of comparing cost before and after intervention?

Tags: logistic, panel-data, wilcoxon-signed-rank

I have a sample of 200 patients, with data for 2 years. 
During year 1 they are on treatment A and accumulate overall healthcare costs of X. During year 2 they are on treatment B and accumulate overall healthcare costs of Y.

What is the best method for comparing the overall healthcare costs for treatment A and treatment B? I have been suggested conditional logistic regression, but that doesn't make sense to me (outcome of treatment A or treatment B with continuous variable of cost). The method that makes most sense to me is a paired Wilcoxon test (since the overall healthcare costs are skewed towards most patients being lower costs, and only a few being higher costs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Wilcoxon signed-rank test may work, if the two costs give a flat mean-difference (Bland-Altman) plot.  But your design has treatment completely confounded with time so is unreliable for answering the question.  This should have been a 2-period crossover design, or another design that allows for an adequate control.

The conditional logistic model is for binary outcomes only.

Comment: Yes, the study design is not ideal, but it is an observational study. I have been arguing that the conditional logistic model is not appropriate so it is good to know. The argument against me is that they can consider the treatment as the outcome (A or B) and consider the cost as the variable (so for every 10 dollars, the probability of treatment B is higher). Is there any validity to this?

Comment: If that what they want to know, but it seems like the cart is before the horse on this.  If one spends more money, then the treatment will become B?  KIS. If you only care about the difference between the groups, then go with FH's answer.

Comment: There is some validity to using the logistic model in that way but it's still a crazy idea to reverse the role of independent and dependent variables in this particular situation.  Concerning the non-ideal nature of the observational study, some studies should not be undertaken because there are too likely to provide misleading information.  The only design weaker than the pre-post design is the single-arm design using historical controls.